# Router has traffic coming in, but it's not going anywhere. What can I do?

Tags: router, dd-wrt, traffic

Ok so I have a Linksys WRT-54G v4 running the latest version of DD-WRT (just downloaded it last week to try to fix the problem)

There is consistently about 750kbs coming into the router but from what I can tell, it's not going anywhere inside the LAN or WLAN.  I'm also having a lot of network dropouts while I'm listening to music or watching video over the network.

The traffic is coming in even if there are no computers on the network (turned them all off)

What can I do to fix this problem?  Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

**UPDATE - Ok well I've changed my IP and was still getting the 'traffic' but after further investigation at the modem, found there is no actual data going through.  I'm going to chalk this up to a router on the fritz

Comment: You sure it's not coming from the machine you're viewing this graph from? (If everything else is disconnected...)

Comment: No, the graphing is the 20/30k in the top graph (the LAN traffic)

Answer (score 3):

you might be under some sort of dos attack? If you can install tcp dump on your dd-wrt , run tcpdump on you wan port and see what kind of traffic it is. Collect destination and source ip and dst and src ports, as the dd-wrt has limited storage, capture to ram, or to a remote drive and use wireshark on your workstation to take a closer look at the capture.

It maybe a misconfiguration on the isp side. If it's looking like a dos attack then try changing your ip address, if your still getting dos then contact your isp , they should be able to help.